# parsing date string in python (convert string to date)

Tags: python, datetime-parsing

I have a datetime string in the form of a string as:

```
2011-10-23T08:00:00-07:00
```

How do i parse this string as the datetime object.

I did the following reading the documentation:

```
date = datetime.strptime(data[4],"%Y-%m-%d%Z")
```

BUt I get the error

```
  ValueError: time data '2011-10-23T08:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%Z'
```

which is very clear.

But I am not sure how to read this format.

Any suggestions.
Thanks

Edit: Also, I must add, all I care about is the date part

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Standard datetime.datetime.strptime has problems with timezone definitions. Use [dateutil.parser](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("2011-10-23T08:00:00-07:00")
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 23, 8, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```

If you care about the date part only, you can try it without dateutil.parser:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(data[4].partition('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2011, 10, 23)
```