# Reformatting dates in python

Tags: python, date, reformatting

I'm stuck with this python problem, I have a date in the format of month-day-year and I need to change it to year-month-day format

Comment: Show me how the date looks like ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985312/parsing-date-string-in-python-convert-string-to-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("06/03/2015", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2015-06-03'
```

---

This takes a date (June 3, 2015 in this case) as a string and parses it to a datetime object using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). It then converts that to a string in the format you requested (YYYY-mm-dd) using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)